# Shinyapps.io error using mdy_hms() on server but works locally

Tags: r, lubridate, shinyapps

So this is a very large complex project, but I'll do my best to provide reproducible examples. In essence my script reads in a folder full of csv files and mutates one of them using the mdy_hms() function from the Lubridate library.

```
input$dir /---
 file1.csv
 file2.csv, etc.

files <- list.files(input$dir, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  set_names() %>% 
  map_dfr(read_csv, .id = "file") %>% 
  mutate(datetime = mdy_hms(timestamp),
         date = as.Date(datetime),
         DeployID = as.character(`tag-local-identifier`),
         Latitude = `location-lat`,
         Longitude = `location-long`) %>% 
  distinct(DeployID, datetime, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

This block of code above works just fine on my local machine. However when I publish this to my IO instance, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Error in mutate: Problem while computer `datetime = mdy_hms(timestamp)`.
Caused by error in `as.character()`:
~ cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

I have confirmed the data coming in via the map_dfr field has a column called datetime and is of type chr. I really don't understand why I'm getting this error. Is it come kind of mask issue? Maybe I'll try adding the lubridate:: to the mdy_mhs call but seems unlikely to me.

Comment: ```utils::timestamp``` is a function; this tells me that your data doesn't have a column called timestamp (cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'). Check your dataset and make sure if you are using the right name. best practice is to rename it to something like `P_timestamp` to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Thanks M-- I basically came to that same conclusion myself shortly after I posted this. Sadly I'm not in control of how the data is going to come to me (via 3rd party). Can I just recast that column name into P_timestamp before the mutate?

Comment: yeah, but I am still not sure if there is a timestamp column in the original to begin with. Check the names, and rename it before mutate to have tidy names without any conflict.